# how to check if directory exists with Storage:: facade in laravel?

Tags: file, laravel, storage

What is the counterpart of:

```
if (!File::exists($path))
```

using `Storage::` in Laravel 5.1 ?

Anyone?

Answer (score 54):

Try this:

```
// To check if File exists in Laravel 5.1
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->has('file.jpg');

// To check if File exists in Laravel 5.2
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->exists('file.jpg');
```

Comment: talking about a directory, not file.

Comment: @Chriz74 The `exists` function works fine for directories, so `->exists('dirname');` will work.

Comment: Directories are just files that contain files.

Comment: The OP **EXPLICITLY** asked about directories. The task is NOT just to determine if "/foo/bar/something" exists in the filesystem, but ALSO if it is a directory.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova But regular files AREN'T, and the requirement here is to be able to determine WHETHER a given "file" is one that can "contain other files" OR not.

Comment: I thought that author aswer could put examples with folders... and add explain that folders too are files...

Answer (score 30):

If you want to check if a directory exists and create one if doesn't exist, this code will work for you.

```
if(!Storage::exists('/path/to/your/directory')) {

    Storage::makeDirectory('/path/to/create/your/directory', 0775, true); //creates directory

}
```

Comment: As of at least Laravel 7, Storage::makeDirectory() only accepts the path as a parameter. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#directories

Comment: The method `makeDirectory()` will only accept one parameter. This is the correct one `if (Storage::missing($storagePath)) Storage::makeDirectory($storagePath);`

Comment: The parameters that Prateek is mentioning here are for the File::makeDirectory method

Answer (score 11):

If you want to check for a directory, try this:

```
if (Storage::directories($directory)->has('someDirectory')) {
    ....
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#directories

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-has

Comment: I think `exists` will only work with Laravel 5.2. Isn't it?

Comment: No, it's working since 5.0 (not sure about Laravel 4 though): https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage

Comment: But, as per `https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem`, the `has` method may be used to determine if a given file exists on the disk.

Comment: And as per `https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem`, the `exists` method may be used to determine if a given file exists on the disk.

Comment: @prava, it's there: https://github.com/illuminate/filesystem/blob/master/Filesystem.php#L21

Comment: Thanks but I am talking about a path not a file.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin ok but I read in the Storage API that it doesn't rely on directories because some services don't use it, like for example Amazon AWS which uses objects that can look as directories but are not directories, so how will the app behave on AWS if I check that, create the directory and put files into it?

Comment: @Chriz74, I do not use AWS, so I can't help you here. Your original question was about directories. You can try imy solution on AWS and tell us if it's working or not. )

Comment: The `directories` function returns an array, not a Collection, so `has()` cannot be used.

Comment: HORRIBLY INEFFICIENT. Reads entire containing directory, processes entries one by one and INTERNALLY checks whether they are directories (and somehow it MANAGES to do it, even though "AWS doesn't have concept of directories yadda yadda"), then returns all the ones that are directories, then YOU must check whether the item of interest is in the returned set.

Answer (score 7):

There are two things to check: (1) that the path exists, and (2) that the path is a directory.

This will check the path exists (syntax for Laravel 5.2+), no matter whether it is a file or a directory:

```
Storage::exists('your-path') // bool
```

Once you know it exists, this will confirm the path is a directory:

```
Storage::getMetadata('your-path')['type'] === 'dir'
```

The underlying `Flysystem` library will cache what it can when inspecting the filesystem (which may be local or remote), so in normal circumstances these two functions will only make one call to the filesystem.

Comment: This actually works (and answers the question), also after selecting a disk. Oneliner: `if (!(Storage::disk('mydisk')->exists($path) && Storage::disk('mydisk')->getMetadata($path)['type'] === 'dir')) { echo "path '$path' is not a directory"; }`

Answer (score 6):

Another way for laravel 5.5 using Storage Facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
if(Storage::exists('/mnt/files/file.jpg')) {
    dd('file esxists');
} else {
    dd('no file found');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$exists = Storage::disk('local')->has('**dirname**');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('your folder name'))
{
    //what you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 8.x you can use this condition:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($path)) 
{
    // 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in laravel 5.4
`$exists = Storage::disk('public')->exists('images/test_image.jpg');`
 - with `'public'` that was config in filesystem.php

```
'public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

`'images/test_image.jpg'` is the path of image.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can easily do that via File Facade `File::isDirectory($YOURDIRECTORYPATHHERE);` this will return boolean based on existence!

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who use `Storage::disk()`, Laravel v9 appears to make use of `directoryExists()`.

```php
Storage::disk('name')->directoryExists($path);
```

Link to [directoryExists](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L223) method.

Comment: This method does not exist

Comment: @MrEduar I can confirm that it does in fact exist. I use it in one of my own Laravel 9 projects. Whether or not it exists in Laravel 10 I have not yet confirmed it, but such would be outside the scope of my answer.

Comment: It's true, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve all of the directories as an array then check if the directory (path) is there.

```
$dir = 'dir/path';
$existingDirs = Storage::disk(env('FILE_SYSTEM'))->allDirectories();
if (!in_array($dir, $existingDirs)) {
    // dir doesn't exist so create it
}
```

Comment: Ironically, this is the only one that actually answers the question asked, though it is not an efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `Storage::isDirectory()`.
`Storage::class` is an instance of `\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem` and it contains a method `isDirectory` for checking if a given path exists and if it is directory or not.

```php
    if(Storage::isDirectory("images")){
    // you code...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if(!Storage::disk('ads')->exists(auth()->user()->id)) {
        Storage::disk('ads')->makeDirectory(auth()->user()->id, 0775, true); //creates directory
    }
```

Comment: this create a folder by user id in ads disk you can change it to local or public

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 if (!file_exists(Storage::path($pathToDir))) {
  Storage::makeDirectory('path to directory', 0775, true); 
    // or any code
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is too old to answer, but you may try:

`is_dir($path)`

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
if (Storage::missing($storagePath)) {
    Storage::makeDirectory($storagePath);
}
```