# Laravel Validation on storage path

Tags: laravel, validation

As an example of Laravel validation:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'title' => ['required', 'unique:posts', 'max:255'],
    'body' => ['required'],
]);
```

I want to add path exists or not in storage .

```
Storage::exists('/path/to/your/directory');
```

Based on this I want to do something like :

```
 $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'title' => ['required', 'unique:posts', 'max:255'],
        'body' => ['required'],
        'path' => ['storage_file_exists_or_not']
    ]);
```

How to achieve that. Thanks.

Comment: Is the user going to be setting the directory? why do you want to validate the dir through the validate function?

Comment: yes.  user will send storage path.

Ex. path = app/public

Comment: You can write a custom validation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452059/2609521 Then check if the dir exists https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402410/2609521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom rule using

```
php artisan make:rule StorageFileExists
```

and specify your condition inside the passes function and write your message.

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class StorageFileExists implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return (Storage::exists($value)) ? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'File is present.';
    }
}
```

and write validation rule like this

```
$request->validate([
    'path'      =>  new StorageFileExists(), // your Rulename
]);
```